# Databinding - ObservableField<String> not updating view

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have simple app - `Button` - which fetches data from rest api and a `TextView` where this data is displayed. I'm using *MVVM* architectural pattern. When *ViewModel* receives callback with fetched data I set it up to an ObservableField. Unfortunately it doesn't update text on the screen, but whenever I rotate device data is being updated on the screen.

OK, enough talking, I'll show you the code:

*ViewModel*

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel{

private ObservableField<String> name = new ObservableField<>();

@Override
public void onListReceived(String username) {
    super.onListReceived(list);
    name.set(username);
}

public String getName() {
    return name.get();
}}
```

and in XML:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{viewModel.name}"
        tools:text="some text"/>
```

As far as I read, I think it should be '=' in this line             `android:text="@{viewModel.name}"` between '`@`' and '`{`', but when I add it, clean project and rebuild this, I got an error that Cannot resolve `DataBindingComponent`.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `getName()` method, and make `name` be `public`. Or, have `getName()` return `name`, not `name.get()`.

The data binding system needs to be working directly with the `Observable`. Right now, your `Observable` is hidden from data binding, and so data binding has no way of registering an observer and knowing when the data changes.

> As far as I read, I think it should be '=' in this line android:text="@{viewModel.name}" between '@' and '{',

That syntax (`@={viewModel.name}`) is for two-way data binding. Since the user cannot enter data into a `TextView`, that is not needed here.

Comment: Your post should be saved as a part of documentation, thanks!
I'll accept  your answer in a second.